# how to include multiple jquery files

Tags: javascript

is it possible to include multiple jquery files like this one ?

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
        attach: function(context) {
    //my code
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

I use this to include the files

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.test1.js');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.test2.js');
```

both files are loaded but it seems that only the first is executed while test2 is ignored

can you help me with that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Behaviors, behavior name don't need to be the same as module name. And it cannot be repeated, unless you want to disable earlier implementation.

If you separated your code, it means it's there to do different things. So just name them accordingly, like `Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleDoSomething` and `Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleDoOtherThing`.

Comment: that did the job !